# Email client within a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins, email-client

I need my application to have a module with email functionality. 
This will have all the functionality of an email client. Each user will 
have an inbox, outbox, sent folder, custom folders, sub folders etc. 
They should be able to send, receive,forward, reply to emails. 
Is there any gem/plugin I can use for this? If there is an alternative to building this like integration with Google Apps etc. then please suggest.

Comment: @pankajbhageria: do you need more information in order to accept my answer? Do you need any more help?

Answer (score 5):

You could simply use [ActionMailer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html). Take a look at [this guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) to see if it fits your requirements.